# S3 bucket policy multiple conditions

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm looking to grant access to a bucket that will allow instances in my VPC full access to it along with machines via our Data Center. Without the `aws:SouceIp` line, I can restrict access to VPC online machines.

I need the policy to work so that the bucket can only be accessible from machines within the VPC AND from my office.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1496253408968",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1496253402061",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-dcb634bf",
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<MY PUBLIC IP>"                                  
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying and what difficulties are you experiencing?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried creating it as two separate ALLOW policies -- one with sourceVPC, the other with SourceIp? That would create an OR, whereas the above policy is possibly creating an AND.

Comment: I have put a relevant answer with working code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600490/s3-bucket-access-policy-deny-on-ip-range-and-vpc-endpoint-not-working/76477632#76477632

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a policy whose `Effect` is to `Deny` access to the bucket when `StringNotLike` Condition for both keys matches those specific wildcards.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1496253408968",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1496253402061",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-dcb634bf",
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<MY PUBLIC IP>"                                  
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The second condition could also be separated to its own statement. AWS applies a logical OR across the statements. <sup>[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#access_policies-json)</sup>

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1496253408968",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1496253402061",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-dcb634bf",                                
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1496253402062",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<MY PUBLIC IP>"                                  
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS has predefined condition operators and keys (like aws:CurrentTime). Individual AWS services also define service-specific keys.

As an example, assume that you want to let user John access your Amazon SQS queue under the following conditions:

The time is after 12:00 p.m. on 7/16/2019

The time is before 3:00 p.m. on 7/16/2019

The request comes from an IP address within the range 192.0.2.0 to 192.0.2.255 or 203.0.113.0 to 203.0.113.255.

Your condition block has three separate condition operators, and all three of them must be met for John to have access to your queue, topic, or resource.

The following shows what the condition block looks like in your policy. The two values for aws:SourceIp are evaluated using OR. The three separate condition operators are evaluated using AND.

```
"Condition" :  {
      "DateGreaterThan" : {
         "aws:CurrentTime" : "2019-07-16T12:00:00Z"
       },
      "DateLessThan": {
         "aws:CurrentTime" : "2019-07-16T15:00:00Z"
       },
       "IpAddress" : {
          "aws:SourceIp" : ["192.0.2.0/24", "203.0.113.0/24"]
      }
}
```

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I think that there is a better solution with AWS new capabilities. Especially, I don't really like the `deny` / `StringNotLike` combination, because denying on an s3 policy can have unexpected effects such as locking your own S3 bucket down, by denying yourself (this could only be fixed by using the root account, which you may not have easily accessible in a professional context)

So the solution I have in mind is to use `ForAnyValue` in your condition ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html)). e.g something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1496253408968",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1496253402061",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-sam-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": [
                         "vpc-dcb634bf",
                         "<MY PUBLIC IP>"       
                    ]                              
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```